# Load scripts inside innerHTML

Tags: javascript

After getting rebuked on here, I tried to recode this from scratch. I need to have a JS file load for an HTML file that appears in a div...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getInclude(strIncludeContainer, strIncludeURL)
{
  var strPage = '';
  var intIndexOfBodyOpen = 0;
  var intIndexOfBodyClose = 0;
  var objXhttp;

  objXhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  objXhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
      strPage = this.responseText;
      intIndexOfBodyOpen = strPage.indexOf('<body>');
      intIndexOfBodyClose = strPage.indexOf('</body>');
      document.getElementById(strIncludeContainer).innerHTML = strPage.substring(intIndexOfBodyOpen + 6, intIndexOfBodyClose);
    }
  };
  objXhttp.open("GET", strIncludeURL, true);
  objXhttp.send();
}

        getInclude("divUnifiedAppWording", "../mpage/Unified_App_Wording");

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "../resource/resmgr/scripts/unified_app.js";
$container.appendChild(script);
        </script>


<div id="divUnifiedAppWording"></div>
```

function getInclude works fine, but I can't get the Javascript in unified_app.js to load. For reference, in unified_app.js I have the following script:

```
const date = new Date();
let offset = 0;
const threshold = new Date();
threshold.setMonth(3); //January is 0!
threshold.setDate(3);
if (Date.now() > threshold) { 
  offset = 1;
}
var theDate = new Date();
var award_year1 = date.getFullYear() + offset;
var award_year2 = date.getFullYear() + 1 + offset;

console.log(award_year1);
console.log(award_year2);
```

I am really lost with this after spending several days trying to figure out a solution to my problem! I feel like it should not be this difficult to find a simple solution to this issue. Hopefully I'm not barking up the wrong tree here... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to load a script file is by creating a `script` element.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "../resource/resmgr/scripts/unified_app.js";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed my code above to reflect my understanding of your suggestion. Unfortunately, this is still not working :(

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Yes, i am getting the following error, which I don't understand:

Comment: unreachable code after return statement[Learn More]
combined.js:604:1
ReferenceError: $container is not defined[Learn More]
Bozarth:351:1
unreachable code after return statement[Learn More]

Comment: You aren't supposed to just paste it. You need to examine the code they provided, and then properly integrate it into yours.

Comment: @beingbecoming Your code has `$container.appendChild(script);`, I assumed you defined `$container` elsewhere in your script.

Comment: I don't think the unreachable code messages have anything to do with my code.

Comment: The important part of that error is the "`ReferenceError: $container is not defined`".

Comment: @Barmar I did not. I'm trying to retrofit code created by a previous developer.

Comment: Use `document.head` instead.

Comment: Sorry I disappeared... I got sucked into tinkering.

Comment: I got everything to come back clean now EXCEPT I'm now getting a different error unreachable code after return statement

Comment: You have a function somewhere that has a statement after `return`. Since `return` exits the function, it makes no sense to do that.

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I still haven't gotten the script to work properly in the innerHTML, so I figured this could have been part of the problem. When I load the page-in-a-page along the date-calc script runs fine.

Comment: I'm not sure why the warning is only when you use dynamic loading. But you might want to check this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Stmt_after_return which shows the common causes.

Comment: I did some troubleshooting and the console is coming back clean. It does the date calculations on the console. The issue is `<script>document.write(award_year1);</script>` is not producing anything (even if I put "hello" inside the document write it doesn't produce while using innerHTML but it does when just loaded by itself.

Comment: You shouldn't use `document.write()` in scripts that run after the page has loaded. It will wipe out the current document.

Answer (score 1):

Scripts appended to the page using JavaScript only load if they are explicitly created, like using `document.createElement`. Barmar's answer covers this just fine in your particular case, and you should absolutely use his answer if you can. Otherwise, assuming every other part of your code is functional, if you're looking for a more dynamic approach, it should work if you replace this line...

```
document.getElementById(strIncludeContainer).innerHTML = strPage.substring(intIndexOfBodyOpen + 6, intIndexOfBodyClose);
```

...with these lines.

```
var includeContainer = document.getElementById(strIncludeContainer);
includeContainer.innerHTML = strPage.substring(intIndexOfBodyOpen + 6, intIndexOfBodyClose);
var scripts = includeContainer.getElementsByTagName("script");
for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    if(scripts[i].text) {
        script.text = scripts[i].text;
    } else {
        for(var j = 0; j < scripts[i].attributes.length; j++) {
            if(scripts[i].attributes[j].name in HTMLScriptElement.prototype) {
                script[scripts[i].attributes[j].name] = scripts[i].attributes[j].value;
            }
        }
    }
    scripts[i].parentNode.replaceChild(script, scripts[i]);
}
```

This basically just clones every script element from the container, obviously initiated with `document.createElement` so that it actually works, and then replaces the original script elements with the cloned ones.